# CSS Fluid Width inside div with fixed width

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have two divs inside a wrapper div of width 880px.

The first div contains an image which can be any width, I'd like the second width to scale with it i.e:

Div 1 = 300px
Div 2 = 580px << this div scales to fit the parent div.

Setting a width of 100% on the second div ignores the fixed width on the parent div.

Is this possible using only css or would I have to use javascript/jquery (jquery is already loaded so it's not too big a hassle)?

Thanks!

Comment: If the parent is fixed, why don't you make the child fixed too?

Comment: You want two columns, right? One that shrinks to its content, and one that takes up the rest of the width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS, you can only set dimensions that are directly relative to an element's content, one if its parents, the font size, or to the screen resolution, but not to the dimensions of its siblings.* This means that, in order for the second block to be the same width as the image, it should "inherit" the width from a parent, or have it set dynamically. For example:

```
#wrapper {
    float: left;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <img id="image" src="…" alt="" />
    <div id="fits_img">…</div>
</div>
```

The `float` property on the `#wrapper` block makes its width fit its contents. The width of the `#fits_img` block is `auto` or `100%` by default (since it's a `div` element), so its width will fit `#wrapper` and therefore be indirectly relative to the width of the image.

If you can't make the `#wrapper` element float, you could also mirror the width with jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#fits_img').width($('#image').width());
});
```

---

* Note that there are also absolute units like 'cm', but they're relatively useless and rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

copy/paste the code below and try changing the image's width and see what happens.

```
<div style="width:880px;">
    <img style="float:left;margin-right:10px;width:600px;height:80px;" src="whatever" />
    <div>a sadasd wqe sad asdqwe qweqwedasdasdqwe qwe qwe </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```